# Java String как получить ссылку?

Tags: java

Не подскажите как получить ссылку на обьект в пуле стрингов на определенную строку? Например когда мы создаем обьект его дефолтный метод toString выдает его сcылку скажем "Person@2f92e0f4", а как получить ссылку на обьект в пуле стрингов?

Updated:
Я проходил собеседование в Сбербанк, и там был такой вопрос:

```
String s1="Hello";
String s2="Hello";
String s3=new String("Hello");
String s4=new String("Hello");
System.out.println(s1==s2);
System.out.println(s2==s3);
System.out.println(s3==s4);
```

Что выведется в консоль?
правильный вариант ответа:

true false false

Это все было в виде теста с вариантами ответов. Насчет s1==s2 понятно ведь джава проверяет есть ли такая строка в пуле или нет, если нет создает новую, если да то просто в s2 копируется ссылка s1 на эту же строку в пуле стрингов. Но почему s3==s4 false? как посмотреть ссылки на эти обьекты?

Comment: не очень понял что именно и зачем вам нужно...опишите, пожалуйста, задачу которую вы изначально решали и как пришли к этому вопросу.

Comment: хорошо сейчас подправлю

Comment: Потому что в s3 и s4 ты явно создаешь новый объект через конструктор

Comment: хорошо, а есть ли способ посмотреть ссылки этих обьектов?

Comment: Это вопрос про String Pool... напишу ответ

Comment: но он не за 5 минут пишется, так что подойдите через полчасика

Comment: Person@2f92e0f4 - это не ссылка на объект, а название класса + @ + hashcode `getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`

Comment: @DanilApsadikov Ааа, я все время ложно полагал что это ссылка на обьект

Comment: через 10 мин ответ будет, комментарий Данила суть не раскрывает к сожалению, и на собеседовании такой ответ не примут

Comment: @МихаилРебров хорошо, хорошо, заранее спасибо за труды!)

Comment: Там если что я небольшую ошибку допустил в коде перемещения строк в пул. уже поправил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Описанный вами вопрос касался не всех объектов, а особенностей хранения строк в памяти.

Смысл в том, что строки созданные с помощью конструктора и строковые литералы хранятся немного по разному.

- Строки созданные с помощью конструктора, как и полагается, хранятся в куче(Java Heap Memory)
- Строковые литералы же хранятся в специально отведенном месте, которое называется  пул строк(String Pool)

Задача String Pool - эффективная работа со строками и оптимизация их хранения.

В вашем примере

```
String s1 = "Hello";
String s2 = "Hello";
String s3 = new String("Hello");
String s4 = new String("Hello");
```

Идем с начала.

1. У вас появляется литерал `"Hello"`, который попадает в String Pool
2. Далее Вы кладёте в переменную s1 ссылку на `"Hello"` в String Pool
3. Далее при использовании того же литерала `"Hello"` вы получаете ту же ссылку на то же место в String Pool (и это одна из его задач: чтобы не забивать всю память одними и теми же литералами)
4. После чего Вы кладёте ту же ссылку на то же место в переменную s2, после чего переменные s1 и s2 хранят одинаковые ссылки, которые ведут в String Pool
5. Далее Вы создаете объект с помощью конструктора и он уже размещает значение переменной не в String Pool, а в общей области Java Heap Memory
6. Тоже самое происходит с переменной s4

В итоге получается, что:
Переменные s1 и s2 ссылаются на один и тот же участок памяти специально созданный для оптизации хранения строковых литералов.
А под переменные s3 и s4 выделялись отдельные участки памяти(для каждой) в куче(Java Heap Memory)

Что и соответствует выводу

```
true
false
false
```

#### Перемещение строк в String Pool

Также стоит понимать, что вы можете переместить строки созданные с помощью конструктора в пул строк.

Для этого есть метод `intern()` который перемещает строку в String Pool и возвращает ссылку на аналогичную строку в пуле, при этом если такая строка уже была в пуле, то вы получите ссылку на нее.

И если мы попробуем сделать так

```
String s1 = "Hello";
String s2 = "Hello";
String s3 = (new String("Hello")).intern();
String s4 = (new String("Hello")).intern();

System.out.println(s1==s2);
System.out.println(s2==s3);
System.out.println(s3==s4);
```

то на выводе получим, что все они равны

```
true
true
true
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Подробнее:**

- https://topjava.ru/blog/rukovodstvo-po-string-pool-v-java

Comment: а есть ли способ получить ссылку вообще на любой обьект в куче? просто глянуть хоть как она выглядит то?)а то просто говорят что переменная содержит ссылку на обьект и тд а где она и как выглядит не понятно

Comment: @Venoman9867 Вы ими и так постоянно оперируете сохраняя и передавая их. Взглянуть?... с точки зрения безопасности Java не дает напрямую работать с памятью и поэтому она заняла свою нишу в корпоративном секторе и во многом поэтому она сейчас крутится в каждом банке. Так что вынужден буду Вас разочаровать. Если хотите посмотреть на значение адресов памяти, то вам в `C++`

Comment: @Venoman9867 все говорят, потому что нужно понимать как устроено то с чем ты работаешь. Стека и Кучи вы тоже никогда не увидите вживую, тем не менее это не значит, что вам не стоит про них знать